# Error - a function definition is not allowed here before { token

Tags: c++

The code for this project is working, other than this one error. I know it has to do with the int main() but I'm not sure how to fix it. Lines 19,23,27.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

// FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
double radius;
double area;
double circumference;
double diameter;
char letter;

// FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
int main() {

    cout<<"Please enter an 'A' to compute the area, a 'C' to compute the circumference, or a 'D' to compute the diameter, followed by the radius of circle: ";
    cin>>letter>>radius;

double area (double radius){    
     double area=M_PI*(radius*radius);
        return area;
}
double circumference (double radius){
    double circumference=2*(M_PI*radius);
        return circumference;
}
double diameter (double radius){    
     double diameter=2*radius;
        return diameter;
}

switch(letter){
    case 'A':
        cout<<"Area of circle: "<<area<<"\n";
        break;
    case 'C':
    cout<<"Circumference of circle: "<<circumference<<"\n";
            break;
    case 'D':
    cout<<"Diameter of circle: "<<diameter;
            break;
            }   
            }
```

Comment: It is not necessary to shout PLEASE HELP when asking here. It's already very clear that you need help, or you wouldn't be posting a question here in the first place. Adding that unnecessary noise will not get you help any faster. Spending more time clearly describing the problem and asking a specific question will speed things up. The error message is pretty clear. You can't define functions inside `main()`.

Comment: I recommend formatting your code in a bit more of a conventional way. It's hard to tell what's going on with all the curlies all over the place.

Comment: If you absolutely have to have the functions defined inside main, you could use lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double area(double radius);
double circumference(double radius);
double diameter(double radius);

int main(){
    // FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
    double radius;
    double a;
    double c;
    double d;
    char letter;

    cout<<"Please enter an 'A' to compute the area, a 'C' to compute the circumference, or a 'D' to compute the diameter, followed by the radius of circle: ";
    cin>>letter>>radius;

    switch(letter){
        case 'A':
            //call-function here
            a = area(radius);
            cout<<"Area of circle: "<<a<<"\n";
            break;
        case 'C':
            //call-function here
            c = circumference(radius);
            cout<<"Circumference of circle: "<<c<<"\n";
            break;
        case 'D':
            //call-function here
            d = diameter(radius);
            cout<<"Diameter of circle: "<<d;
            break;
    }
}

double area (double radius){    
    double area=M_PI*(radius*radius);
    return area;
}
double circumference (double radius){
    double circumference=2*(M_PI*radius);
    return circumference;
}
double diameter (double radius){    
    double diameter=2*radius;
    return diameter;
}
```

you need to declare the functions sign before the main() and the function at below.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define functions within a function (including your `main` function). You'll need to do it before the main or declare a function signature before the `main` and implement the function after the `main`.